# Implications and cause for static discharge

Tags: damage, leakage-current, static-electricity

For months, I've had a potential buildup culminating in static discharge when touching the chassis of my macbook pro at ONE location. No source could be identified (no ground leakage – I checked with multiple multimeters at multiple locations in the office, happened with and without a grounded power supply, etc) and I concluded it must be the laminate floor and low humidity levels in the office. I ended up buying a humidifier and decided I would need to live with it.

It seems I have now identified the (potential!) culprit: a multi socket extension with a loose contact. The railing of the plug was not fully connected with the neutral wire. This was loose. However, there was very little discoloration (and hence spark buildup).
[image: the inside of the multi-socket extension; the neutral wire was not fully soldered on]

This was only noticeable months later, as the connection would sometimes fully break if another device was attached to the multi-socket extension, causing the faulty contact to move and hence cause all devices on the extension not be powered. No fuse blew, no device was noticeably harmed. After the second occurrence, I retired the extension and took it apart to investigate.

My questions:

1. Do you think this loose contact (not causing any disruptions, blackouts or the like) could be the reason for the perceived ground leakage?
2. None of the previously attached devices (used for 12+ hours per day over 12 months) are noticeably damaged; do you think there might still be the chance for long-term damage? Specifically, what are the implications of potential build up on the metal chassis of a laptop – which components would be damaged first?

Thanks!

Comment: Your assumption is an intermittent static issue for an intermittent power contact problem.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 does that sound feasible to you?

Comment: An intermittent power or neutral contact is certainly a problem that you can solve. But it doesn’t sound like a static insulation problem.